# A library in JavaScript for XML parsing with namespaces?

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer

I have a handful of code that uses the DOM to parse and traverse some XML data. It works fine on Gecko and WebKit but, of course, IE absolutely chokes on it. Is there a library for an XML DOM that supports:

- `getAttributeNS`
- `localName`
- `namespaceURI`

Support for IE7 is about as far back as I need to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you want to go this route, but this can be done with MSXML using their nonstandard way of doing things. MSXML 3.0 comes with IE 6 and later.

I haven't actually done this ;-) but this might be what you need:

`IXMLDOMNamedNodeMap.getQualifiedItem` looks like `getAttributeNS`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757075.aspx

`IXMLDOMNode` has a `namespaceURI` property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763813.aspx

`IXMLDOMNode.baseName` looks like `localName`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms767570.aspx

Comment: I was hoping there would be some library to abstract the differences between different platforms... :(

Comment: You'll probably have to write your own.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to safely and easily parse XML in Internet Explorer. This tutorial [Easy XML Consumption using jQuery](http://www.compoc.com/tuts/) will give you a more in-depth information on how you can do it.

Comment: Yes, but I need proper namespace support; as in it must support lookup of attributes/nodes with a namespace URI.

Comment: Right, you can do so by using `.find("[nodeName=foo:bar]")`

Comment: You don't seem to understand what I need -- I need to be able to find nodes with namespace URIs; i.e. if I had `xmlns:foo="http://www.example.com/ns"`, I want to be able to find `foo:bar` with only `http://www.example.com/ns` available, and not to use the `foo:` prefix to find tags.

Comment: Consuming namespaced xml with jQuery is a pain. And "find nodeName" doesn't work in jQuery 1.7.